# Timer refresh page in a function

Tags: javascript, php

In my function I have a page refresh at the end to actually update the table, however the refresh is faster than the database.

Anyone have an idea how I can change this?

```
echo '<script>                                                                          ';
echo 'function updateId(id) {                                                             ';
echo 'var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();                                               ';
echo '    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {                                     ';
echo '        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)                     ';
echo '        {                                                                         ';
//echo '            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);                                          ';
echo '        }                                                                         ';
echo '    };                                                                            ';
echo '    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?id=" +id, true);                              ';
echo '    xmlhttp.send();                                                               ';
echo 'location.reload(true);                                                                ';

echo '}                                                                                 ';
echo '</script>                                                                         ';
?>
```

Comment: put the location.reload inside the readystate check, also you dont need to echo every line

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence! That works for me ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This usually happens when the DOM hasn't been loaded and before that your other tasks finishes their job(in the case page refresh).To solve this problem without any framework you can `addEventListener`.

```
echo '<script>';
echo 'document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function updateId(id) {';
echo 'var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();';
echo '    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {';
echo '        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)';
echo '        {';
//echo '            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);';
echo '        }';
echo '    };';
echo '    xmlhttp.open("GET", "update.php?id=" +id, true);';
echo '    xmlhttp.send();';
echo 'location.reload(true);';
echo '}';
echo '});';
echo '</script>
```

The **`DOMContentLoaded`** event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets, images, and subframes to finish loading.